# Highcharts adds additional space below legend item when using subscript '₂'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, unicode, highcharts

Hoping someone can help with an issue with Highcharts I've run into.

The data we're using for our series titles contains a Unicode subscript 2, specifically U+2082 '₂' (as part of displaying CO₂).

When creating the legend, Highcharts renders this title with additional space below that legend item as shown in the [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKsEN.png).

This occurs on Firefox and IE11, not on Chrome, untested on Safari.

I first assumed this was being caused by the font provided, but I've been unable to make the space disappear, even when using a fonts that fully support unicode.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction for getting rid of this space. Thanks in advance.

Heres a working JSFiddle showing the problem, which occurs on IE11 and Firefox for certain.

https://jsfiddle.net/v4sxj27t/

```
{
  name: "CO₂ Series",
  data: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
},
```

UPDATE 25/03/2016

More info after research.
The actual height of the `<text>` tag containing the legend item with the CO₂ is 3 pixels larger than the others - makes sense, as the '₂' descends further than other glyphs when they're all capitals.

What seems to be the problem, is that Highcharts then seems to add an additional 3 pixels spacing below the line containing CO₂, by way of adding it to the transform() attribute of the containing `<g>` element in the SVG. This is visible in the JSFiddle using the firefox dev tools on Windows

Comment: Did you try to give the legends simply a fixed height with the label formatter? I can barely see the problem (OSX, Chrome/FF, almost identically for me, but I am really tired)

Comment: Firefox (45.0.1) on OS X (10.10.5) has no extra space in the legend. Same for Safari (9.1). Contrary the subscript almost touches the line below it.

Comment: Oh wait George, not sure if the labelformatter can set a height (thought so). But at least you can give the legends something like itemMarginTop: 3 to set a little space. That could "solve" it: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.itemMarginTop

Comment: @Tonsenson, Thanks for the reply. Setting a fixed line height with the lineHeight attribute of the itemStyle attribute of the label object doesn't seem to effect the space below the line. If I use the firefox dev tools, I can actually see that the <text> container tag is actually bigger for the CO2 titles. Highcharts then seems to also add a space below this line equal to the increased size of the <text> tag, which doesnt makes no sense i the <text> height has been increased

Comment: @dgw Thanks for letting me know - I've only tested this on a Windows machine, interesting that it doesn't occur on OSX!

Comment: Ok; the itemmargin thing was more an idea to make a bigger gap between the items so the gap below the co2 would be "invisible". Tuff thing!

Comment: @Tonsenson Thanks, I see where you're going with that now - adding the space above would the space below seemingly not there. The problem with that is different fonts add different amounts of spacing below the line, which means we would never know for certain how much space to add in the gap between the items, in case users browsers use a fall back font. Thanks for the suggestion though, much appreciated!

Comment: That's what we are here for :)